# column does not belong to table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I am trying to retrieve fullname of a user from tblUser on the basis of username that is also present in tblUser and show it in textbox.
But it Shows error Column 'FullName' does not belong to table ,even though column FullName and UserName are present in table.
Code Used

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txttfullname" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
DataTable dc = ojc.GetUser(lblusername.Text);
if (dc.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
      txttfullname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
 }

public DataTable GetUser(string UserName)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select *from tblUser where UserName=@UserName";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Something is not as you think because that code should not fail to have a column named "FullName" if it really exists in the table tblUser.

Comment: Check your connection string. You might be using wrong Database in your connection string.

Comment: txttfullname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
 replace dt by dc and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this part right or a typo?

```
DataTable dc = ojc.GetUser(lblusername.Text);
if (dc.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
      txttfullname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
 }
```

fetching the Datatable `dc` and binding with `dt` ?

Another **Question**

Does `lblusername.Text` and `dc` has the values, did you debug and check?

Comment: @ Ruban.j Thank You sir .Was problem with dc and dt